# Android text to speech issue

Tags: java, android

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

I was going to add this but how can i add it if my main activity where it will get the text etc already has this `implements OnClickListener` and then that tutorail has this `implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your activity so it reads

```
implements OnClickListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

All you need is a comma between multiple things to implement